# Run Server Application in Client Browser

Tags: client

I am working with a relatively small and simple desktop application whose output feeds into a larger web application that I am working on.  I had originally wanted to mimic the desktop app in my web app, so that the end user did not need the desktop app installed locally.  I now know this won't be possible.

So, if I were to install this desktop application on our server, is there anyway a clients browser could run this application outside of Citrix or the like.  The desktop app consists of a series of forms, and I would like them to be accessible at the client.  I have a great deal of freedom with the server, and am still in the design phase, so any and all suggestions welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Java [VNC client applet](http://danielwebb.us/software/vnc/), which will allow the user to remote-control the server.